# She always calls me WHEN

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

My preference goes to number #1. But I am not sure which one is correct.

> 1. She always calls me when she has to go to the hospital.

Or

> 2. She'll always call me when she has to go to the hospital.

Comment: Why do you think one of them is not correct? They're both perfectly good.

Comment: @ColinFine is correct, but this being English, there is a subtle difference in tone. What do you want to project, annoyance or confidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both grammatically correct ways of describing habitual behavior. I would prefer the first version for more formal use, and the second for more conversational, but that is a style issue.